# Command Line to Open .py with IPython

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I would like to use the great IPython Web Interface to open, evaluate, edit and save the following "myfile.py" (see below) avoiding the annoying process: Create an .ipynb > import myfile.py to it > make some evaluation or edition > export to .py > remove unnecessary code lines and finaly get again the following content (myfile.py):

```
import os

# <codecell>

# Number division
print(4/5)

# Number Plus
print(1+40)
```

Is there a command line to do so?

Notes:

- I want work ONLY with .py files, any solution with store/work with .ipynb (JSON files) not be welcome.
- Suggestions for other programs will be very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

On stable version, use the `--script` flag, it always save .py file wihthout having to go through the export process. Still it also save the `.ipynb` file along side.

On dev version there are now pre-save hook that allows you to do whatever you want for saving .

To automatically load `.py` files, you will have to write your own Notebook File Loader backend that accept `.py` files.